# What does print(... sep='', '\t' ) mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, separator

I am having a bit of trouble trying to find an answer to this. I would like to know what the syntax `sep=""` and `\t` means. I have found some informaion about it but I didn't quite understand what the purpose of using the syntax was. I'm looking for an explanation of what it does and when / why you would use it.

An example of `sep=''` being used:

```
print('Property tax: $', format(tax, ',.2f'), sep='')
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`sep=''` in the context of a function call sets the named argument `sep` to an empty string. See the [`print()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print); `sep` is the separator used between multiple values when printing. The default is a space (`sep=' '`), this function call makes sure that there is no space between `Property tax: $` and the formatted `tax` floating point value.

Compare the output of the following three `print()` calls to see the difference

```
>>> print('foo', 'bar')
foo bar
>>> print('foo', 'bar', sep='')
foobar
>>> print('foo', 'bar', sep=' -> ')
foo -> bar
```

All that changed is the `sep` argument value.

`\t` *in a string literal* is an escape sequence for [tab character, horizontal whitespace, ASCII codepoint 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%5Ct#Tab_characters).

`\t` is easier to read and type than the actual tab character. See the [table of recognized escape sequences](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-15) for string literals.

Using a space or a `\t` tab as a print separator shows the difference:

```
>>> print('eggs', 'ham')
eggs ham
>>> print('eggs', 'ham', sep='\t')
eggs    ham
```

Comment: print('Property tax: $', format(tax, ',.2f'), sep='') 

would be an example of a line of code its used in.

Comment: @krona: `sep=''` is not the same thing as `sep""`. See the [`print()` function documenation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print); the code sets the `sep` keyword argument to an empty string.

Comment: @Noumenon: In Python 2, use `from __future__ import print_function`; this is not limited to just Python 3. The question was using `print()` as a function, hence my tailoring to that case.

Comment: By the same logic any Python 2 answer is also good for Python 3 because 2to3 exists. You're causing confusion for Python 2 users by rejecting the edit. I will tag the question as Python 3, but no one ever notices that.

Comment: @Noumenon: there is always going to be some confusion between the two versions. I do link to the function documentation, I call it a *function* and not a *statement*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`sep=''` ignore whiteSpace.
see the code to understand.Without `sep=''`

```
from itertools import permutations
s,k = input().split()
for i in list(permutations(sorted(s), int(k))):
    print(*i)
```

output:

```
HACK 2
A C
A H
A K
C A
C H
C K
H A
H C
H K
K A
K C
K H
```

using `sep=''`
The code and output.

```
from itertools import permutations
s,k = input().split()
for i in list(permutations(sorted(s), int(k))):
    print(*i,sep='')
```

output:

```
HACK 2
AC
AH
AK
CA
CH
CK
HA
HC
HK
KA
KC
KH
```

Answer (score 1):

`sep='\t'` is often used for Tab-delimited file.

Answer (score 0):

The sep='\t' can be use in many forms, for example if you  want to read tab separated value:
Example: I have a dataset tsv = tab separated value NOT comma separated value
df = pd.read_csv('gapminder.tsv').
when you try to read this, it will give you an error because you have tab separated value not csv. so you need to give read csv a different parameter called sep='\t'.

Now you can read:
df = pd.read_csv('gapminder.tsv, sep='\t'), with this you can read the it.