# How to print with append, custom separator, and suppress trailing space in Python 2?

Tags: python, printing, python-2.x, separator, trailing

I'm printing my output in a file with this command:

```
print >> outfile, columns2[0],"\t",columns2[1],"\t",columns2[2]
```

My problem is that I have a "space" at the end of the content of each column.

I know some times it can be solved with `sep`:

```
print('foo', 'bar', sep='')
```

But I don't know how implement `sep` while writing in a file with my above command:

```
print >> outfile
```

Comment: Why don't you  `write` to the file?

Comment: I think he is talking about the space inserted at each comma, not the NL.

Comment: Are you asking about Python 3 or 2? If Python 3, this could be closed-as-duplicate of [python syntax help sep=“”, '\t'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116482/python-syntax-help-sep-t)

Answer (score 2):

The space comes from using the commas in `print` (Python 2.7 ?).

```
print >> outfile, '\t'.join(columns2)
```

Should resolve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

The [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) function can be used to print to any file, not just `sys.stdout`. Try:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print(*columns2, sep="\t", file=outfile)
```

From the documentation on `print()`:

> **print**(**objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout*)
>
> The `file` argument must be an object with a `write(string)` method; if it is not present or `None`, [sys.stdout](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use file `write` method, using write method won't have the extra newline at the end. Recommend to use string join method over `+` operator as well

```
outfile.write('\t'.join(column2))
# add + '\n' if need the new line
# use column2[:2] if you have more items in list and only need slice of them
```

Comment: Your join command is very interesting, but I obtain the following error: "name 'join' is not defined"

Comment: Should not have the error, i have tested working,  make sure you have exactly `'\t'.join` , double check `'\t'.` before the join