# How to print a for loop in the function without using return in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a python program, which gets a value from an XML file and match it with the given code, but I don't know how to print the value with some conditions.

My Python program is:

```
class setMap(getXml):

    def __init__(self, event_log_row):
        self.event_log_row = event_log_row

    def code(self):
        for each in self.event_log_row:
            self.get_map(each)
        # if I use return here, it basically returns only one value, which is understandable.            

    def get_map(self, event_code):
        dict_class = getXml() # Getting XML from another class
        dictionary = dict_class.getdescription()
        for keys, values in dictionary.items():
            if keys == event_code:
                return values  

# I'm not allowed to use for loop or any conditions after this 
code = ['1011', '1015', '1013']
obj = setMap(code)
print(obj.code())
```

Is it possible to achieve what I am intend to achieve, can someone give me some suggestions, plz.

Thanks

Comment: python 2.x or 3.x ? or do you need 100% compatible code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
    def code(self):
        return [self.get_map(each) for each in self.event_log_row]

[print(x) for x in obj.code()]
```

Comment: Thanks jspcal, its working but its getting printed in the same line for example: [Value1, value 2, value 3], even though I have used the print(list(obj.code())). Is there anyway I can print the list, without using for loop.

Comment: You could `print('\n'.join(str(m) for m in obj.code())`

Comment: list comp with printing side effect?

Comment: [print(x) for x in obj.code()] worked, Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

If you get a result of

```
result  = [["One","Two"],["Three"], ["Four","Five","Six"]]        # obj.code() result
```

from your `setMap.code()` you can print this using

```
result  = [["One","Two"],["Three"], ["Four","Five","Six"]]

print(*result, sep ="\n") # unpack outer list for printing 

print( *(b for a in result for b in a), sep ="\n") # flatten inner lists, unpack
```

resulting in

```
['One', 'Two']
['Three']
['Four', 'Five', 'Six']

One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
```

You specify a print-seperator of newline to get them into different lines, no string-join neeeded.

Details on sep: [What does print(... sep='', '\t' ) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116482/what-does-print-sep-t-mean) or [Doku print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)