# How to remove the last comma?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am wondering what the best way to knock off that last comma printed.

```
for i in range(1, 21):
    print(i, end=",")
```

The output should be:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

Comment: `print(*range(1, 21), sep=",")`

Comment: Hey, please accept the answer if it was useful. Ask for further clarification otherwise.

Comment: Aren-Fey

I am just curious about this:

print(*range(1, 21), sep=",")

# what exactly is the (*) doing to this ?

Comment: `print(*range(1, 21), sep=",")` here `*` operator unpacks the sequence, as if you wrote `print(1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 21, sep=",")`.  More on `*` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean) . `sep` is the separator used between multiple values when printing. The default is a space (sep=' '), here we alter `sep` to put `,` between values. More one `sep` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116482/what-does-print-sep-t-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it your way:

```
for i in range(1, 21):
    print(i, end="," if i!=20 else "" )
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

But a better way of doing this would be:

```
print(*range(1, 21), sep=",")
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the most convenient way to do it in Python.
Given any list, it will join the list together with whatever character you give it. This only works with list of strings so we have to convert the lsit of interegers to strings using map(str, your_list).

```
your_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
converted_list_to_string = map(str, your_list)

print(",".join(your_list))
```

If you want a space after the comma, simply add it to the ", ":

```
print(", ".join(your_list))
```

Comment: You need to convert the list to a list of strings before calling join on it `", ".join(map(str, your_list))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a probably bit better way to accomplish your problem:

```
N = 20
# get a generator object with numbers in range 1 to & including N
to_print = range(1, N+1)
# convert all numbers to a string
to_print = map(str, to_print)
# join all numbers with a , in-between
to_print = ','.join(to_print)
# print string!
print(to_print)
```

What is happening here?