# Use range to print [100, 1000, 10000]

Tags: python

I have such a list:

```
for i in [100, 1000, 10000]:
    print(i)
```

How could I reproduce it with range

```
for i in range(100, 10000, 100)
    print(i)
```

the above code does not work as expected.

Comment: The last parameter for the `range` method is stride. Why do you expect it to work the way your 1st code example does?

Comment: `(10 ** x for x in range(2, 5))`

Comment: You are missing `:`.

Comment: `for i in range(3): print ('100'+(i*'0'))` - since it does not matter if you print an integer or a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are printing increasing powers of ten, so you can do this:

```
>>> for i in range(2, 5):
...     print(pow(10, i))
... 
100
1000
10000
```

#### Edit

As Graham observes in the comments, you can also do

```
>>> for i in range(2, 5):
...     print(10 ** i)
... 
100
1000
10000
```

if you prefer the `**` notation for exponentiation.

Comment: For other readers, note also that exponentiation can be done in python using the `**` operator. So the 2nd line could be rewritten as `print(10 ** i)`, where `a ** b` is "a to the power b".

Comment: This is a good solution but I prefer the@Nils Werner solution's.

Comment: @Graham That's a good point; when writing I thought `pow()` was faster than `**`, but apparently they [perform similarly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48848512/5320906), whereas `math.pow` is slower.

Comment: @snakecharmerb it says `math.pow` is faster. Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: @Ayxan you're quite right, that answer says that `math,pow` is "often faster", but potentially less precise.  Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 4):

With a single line:

```
print(*(10 ** n for n in range(2, 5)), sep='\n')
```

Not the `*` operator, [which is used to unpack the tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921893/10147399). The `**` finds powers of 10, and [sep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22116523/10147399) denotes the string which is put between elements `print` outputs.

As @Walter notes in the comments, this method is not particularly efficient for larger ranges. @snakecharmerb's method with a for loop is the recommenced choice in those cases.

Comment: That's neat :-)

Comment: this allocates the whole tuple, not a good idea if the range is big

Comment: @WalterTross Thanks for the feedback, tried to add that in

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options

```
import numpy as np
for i in np.logspace(2, 4, num = 3, endpoint = True, dtype = np.int):
    print(i)
```

or (edit based on @Graham comment)

```
for i in (10**k for k in range(2, 5)):
    print(i)
```

Comment: you shouldn't presume that everyone knows what you mean by `np`

Comment: In the second case, there's absolutely no point in making it a list using the `[` and `]`; it's simply not optimally memory efficient for large ranges, and therefore a bad practice. Instead, you should make it a generator expression using parentheses: `(10**k for k in range(2, 5))`