# How To remove the spaces between generated numbers from by range object in python like stripe() method applying on strings

Tags: python, integer, range, space

Then How I get the Same effect of stripe method but on integers
this is my code to generate out but like

```
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321
```

but the result was : [i want to remove spaces between numbers in one line code after for statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0UsZ.png)

```
for i in range(1,int(input())+1): 
    print(*range(1,i+1),*range(1,i).__reversed__())
```

Comment: Did you check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) for `print()`, about `sep` parameter?

Comment: Use sep keyword in print function: `print(*range(1,i+1),*range(1,i).__reversed__(), sep = '')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does print(... sep='', '\t' ) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116482/what-does-print-sep-t-mean)

Answer (score 1):

Python's `print` has an optional `sep` parameter.

```
for i in range(1, int(input()) + 1): 
    print(*range(1, i + 1), *range(1, i).__reversed__(), sep='')
```

Though that `__reversed__()` call is ugly.

```
for i in range(1, int(input()) + 1): 
    print(*range(1, i + 1), *range(i - 1, 0, -1), sep='')
```

Please note there is also an optional `end` parameter. You may, for instance, not want your `print` to automatically skip to the next line.

```
for i in range(1, int(input()) + 1): 
    print(*range(1, i + 1), sep='', end='')
    print(*range(i - 1, 0, -1), sep='')
```

Comment: Thank U very much,The problem has been resolved

Comment: As a newcomer to Stack Overflow (welcome aboard!), if you feel an answer has resolved your question, you may accept it.

Comment: This is the right answer.  Please remember to click the little check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting a string first and pass that to `print`.

```py
for i in range(1,int(input())+1): 
    line = ''.join(map(str, range(1, i+1)))
    line += ''.join(map(str, reversed(range(1, i))))
    print(line)
```

Comment: Might as well create two strings are use an f-string to piece them together.